# On the Sony Alpha 6300, is there any way to enable Smart Remote by default when powering on?

Tags: sony-camera-api

I'm developing software for the a6300 using the Sony API, for a situation where the rear camera controls will be inaccessible.  The software will do things like stream the live view, adjust exposure, snap photos etc, along with other non-camera functions in a single software app.

Ideally I would just power on the camera remotely (this is working via AC-PW20 adapter), and Smart Remote would already be enabled so I can connect over wifi and control the camera.  More ideal would be control over USB, but as far as I know only Sony knows how to do that (as they do in their Imaging Edge software).

Answer (score 0):

If the Smart Remote app was active/started when you powered off the camera, it will be started automatically on the next power on. This is at least the behaviour in my testing on an Sony Alpha 6300.